# Deleted Visio Stencils Still Show up When Searching Shapes

Tags: visio

I deleted some stencil files from "%UserProfile%\Documents\My Shapes" however when I search for a shape in Visio 2013, it returns results from the deleted *vss file(s).

For Example, if I create a new blank Visio document and from the left hand side, perform a shape search for "AD FS", it will return a couple of shapes from "CnE_EnterpriseV2.5.vss", which is a stencil that i deleted.  If I "click to see all the shapes in this stencil", it will show all the shapes from that stencil.

I've tried...

- emptying my recycle bin;
- deleted %temp% files;
- renaming the "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Visio" folder and restarting Visio

Could Visio be finding this Stencil somewhere other than the "My Stencils" folder?

Answer (score 1):

Please note - the question is a bit off-topic (not a programming question).

Anyways. Visio search works through Windows Search. So your documents needs to be re-indexed by windows indexing service crawler for changes to take effect (this may take awhile). You can also manually force index rebuild from the "Indexing Options" (from control panel).

Comment: Thanks Nikolay!  FYI i too was initially hesitant to post this here but saw other similar Visio questions. - This issue has been driving me crazy.  I'll give it ago and let you know.

Comment: You can try http://www.visguy.com/vgforum/ forum - it's dedicated to Visio.